# Perl: File in to sorted file out

Tags: perl, sorting

I need help with my perl code. I need to be able to read in a file with one word on each line and at minimum 50 lines. I have a code to print each line from the file but how do I take these items sort them and then out put to a new file.

```
while(<>){
chomp;
print "$_ :is in the file";
}
```

I am struggling to figure out how to take in a file and (I think the <> parses the files line by line) out put it to another file.

Comment: `@array = <>` to get all lines. [Sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) them, [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) output file and [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) away.

Comment: so are we talking: open(new_file); foreach $line (@array){ print "$line"; } close(new_file)   Not sure that open is correct

Comment: Those are links to the documentation, if you want to read. You don't have to loop when printing an array -- print takes a list as argument: `print @array`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a more functional approach, as a one-liner:

```
perl -e '$, = "\n"; print sort map { chomp; $_ } <>' input.txt > output.txt
```

This [`print`s](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) a [`sort`ed](http://perldoc.perl.org/sort.html) version of [`map`ping](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) each line through [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html), separated ([`$,`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)) by newlines.

As a standalone script which writes to a predetermined file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w

$, = "\n";

open(my $output, ">", "output.txt")
  or die "Cannot open output.txt: $!\n";

print $output sort map { chomp; $_ } <>;

close $output;
```

Comment: Why first `chomp` and then add a newline?

Comment: @TLP: The last line in the file might not have a newline, in which case it would print on the same line as the next higher value if we didn’t remove and re-add the newlines.

Comment: @TLP: I’m sorry, but I did write my answer separately. There are only so many ways to do such a small task, so there’s necessarily going to be a lot of overlap. In terms of the gaming element of Stack Exchange, appropriating and improving information from other answers is a good strategy—I just didn’t happen to use it here. :P

Comment: @Pavel: That’s odd, it should work with CRLF line endings (since the file handle should be opened with `:crlf` automatically) unless you used `binmode`. A workaround in that case would be to set `local $/ = "\r\n"`.

Comment: The one liner won't work on windows, as single quotes aren't treated the same on windows.

Answer (score 7):

```
perl -we 'print sort <>' input.txt > output.txt
```

Breakdown:

- the file `input.txt` is opened for reading when we use the diamond operator
  `<>`
- `<>` in list context returns all the lines in the file to `sort`
- `sort` sorts the lines alphabetically and returns the list to `print`
- `print` prints the sorted list
- The shell redirects the output from the `perl` command to the file
  `output.txt`

Comment: so if I pass in a file from the command line how would I do the input.txt > output.txt (<> > output.txt)

Comment: Exactly like in my answer. Only you have to put in your own file names, of course.

Comment: This will produce incorrect output if the file doesn't end with a newline.

Comment: @JonPurdy Now I understand why you chomped your lines.. =P